# Indexing urls with hashtag

Tags: seo

I recently built a website using "#" to add/remove content. It works great, creating unique urls for each content. 
Ex:

http://example.com/test/#info-1 
http://example.com/test/#info-2 
http://example.com/test/#content-1 
...

Last week i added my sitemap to Google Webmasters, but its not indexing the urls with "#".
Adding a url with "#" in "Fetch has Google", it automatically removes everything from "#", so the problem should be here.
Going to "Labs" "Instant Preview" in Webmasters and adding a url with "#", it renders successfully the whole page.

How can i index pages with "#" in Google?

Thanks.
Best Regards.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Google can fetch all my JS content..i have to follow that guide to only say to Google Bot to not remove everything after "#" in the url?

Comment: Issue resolved. By using history.pushState. Had to remove all "#" from "href", something that i should have done from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["#" represents a fragment](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/url/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#concept-url-fragment) of a page/URL. It is not supposed to locate a unique content.
Google respects standards of URL and considers URL as the identifier of a page.

If you use fragment of page to locate a content, you are doing it wrong. Google is not.
Better solution is to use real URL (no "#") to locate your content.

If you can not and if you use Ajax, [Google provides a solution](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) for which you need to generate HTML snapshots.